VNC Server Fails to Start Desktop Environment – “Session cleanly exited too early”
I’m having trouble launching the desktop environment for noVNC. After setting up and trying to run the VNC server, I receive the following error
root@localhost:~# vncserver :2 
New Xtigervnc server 'localhost:2 (root)' on port 5902 for display:2. 
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.okGWtL/passwd :2 to connect to the VNC server.

=================== tail /root/.vnc/localhost:2.log ===================
Session startup via '/root/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)! 
Maybe try something simple first, e.g., tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm 
The X session cleanly exited! 
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 16190... success! 

root@localhost:~#

Only the default tigervncserver works. I’ve tried different desktop environments, including XFCE, GNOME, and others, but nothing seems to work. The session always exits too early.

Looks like newer versions of tigervncserver expects the ~/.vnc/xstartup (or ~/.vnc/Xtigervnc-session) script to stay in foreground.
(I am on Ubuntu 21.10 and the ending & is the problem. On 20.04LTS the ending & is not an issue.)
tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/gnome-session

And tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xfce4-session would work
